# How to disable Pepper moving around the room

Tags: python, nao-robot, pepper

If the [power batch](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-4/family/pepper_user_guide/battery-charging_pep.html) is lifted, this means Pepper is probably charging and the motions around the room and the rotations around himself are disabled. Is there a way to forbid those motions and rotations while this [power batch](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-4/family/pepper_user_guide/battery-charging_pep.html) is closed?

Comment: Do you mean: pepper turns around to track the humans and you want to stop that? So it does the tracking with the head only?

Comment: @JLS No, just the rotation of the "legs" - the rotations and movements caused by the wheels on the bottom of Pepper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one time specifically in your application, you can use

- [ALTracker.setMode("Head")](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/trackers/altracker-api.html#ALTrackerProxy::setMode__ssCR) or
- [ALBasicAwareness.setTrackingMode("Head")](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/interaction/autonomousabilities/albasicawareness-api.html#ALBasicAwarenessProxy::setTrackingMode__ssCR)

For a global settings (robot behavior even when not running an app), you can add the following [preference](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/core/alpreferencemanager.html):

- domain: `com.aldebaran.autonomouslife`
- key: `DefaultBasicAwarenessTrackingMode`
- value: `Head`